# Grails controller variables not visible in the views

Tags: grails, view, controller

I am quite new to grails. I just noticed that variables in the controller are not visible in the view. I only can get the variable values when I assign it to a scope. Is this the standard Grails way or am I doing this wrong. Also, is the params scope the correct one to use or should I use sessions, servletContext?

In the Controller

```
String uploadLocation = grailsApplication.config.uploads.location.toString()
params.put "upLoc", uploadLocation
```

In the View

```
<td> <input type="text" value="${params.get('uploc')}/${fileResourceInstance.decodeURL()}"></input></td>
```

I'm very familiar with Ruby on Rails and this is handled very differently in RoR. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like Maricel say, but there's another way (I think it's a default way to do): return the values you want to pass to the view in action function. For example

```
def test = "abc"
def num = 3

return [testInView: test, numInView: num]
```

Then in view you can access ${testInView}, ${numInView}

Another slightly different way: you can neglect the "return" keyword, it's "groovy way" to return the last value of the function.

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass your variable as part of the model through the render method in your controller action, like this:

```
String uploadLocation = grailsApplication.config.uploads.location    
render(model: [uploadLocation: uploadLocation])
```

Then in the view you can just do:

```
<td> 
   <input type="text" value="${uploadLocation}/${fileResourceInstance.decodeURL()}"/>
</td>
```

On the other hand, if this is a value that is defined in the Config.groovy, you can do this as well in your gsp:

```
<%@ page import="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH" %>

<td> 
   <input type="text" value="${CH.config.uploads.location}/${fileResourceInstance.decodeURL()}"/>
</td>
```

For more info check the [Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.3%20Models%20and%20Views).

Answer (score 1):

One interesting side note. If you don't return anything from your action then all variables in the action's scope will be available in your view as described here: http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Models+and+Views

Comment: I do not see this documented on the page you linked, also, is it just action scope variables or class wide as well?